# How do I get Windows Media Center to list my .mp4 files?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center

I've a collection of .mp4 encoded files but how can I get my media center to list those files? I've tried to add a registry key I've found in the internet but it is working only until the next reboot or shutdown? How can I add this permanently so that my media center list those files? My key looks like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mp4]
@="mp4_auto_file"
"PerceivedType"="Video"
```

Comment: What's the registry key you found/tried?

Comment: @techie007: I've added my registry key for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a 3rd party media lib program that should handle this.  I'm partial to media browser: http://www.mediabrowser.tv/ I know it seems a bit much to play mp4s but the experience is a lot better than you get with the stock WMC library functionality.

If you name you videos what their named on IMDB media browser will automatically download movie poster, synopsis, actors, ratings, genre, ext. and display it in a pretty decent interface. You can sort and arrange your collection by ay of that data and look for actors in your collection. You can even hookup daemon tools and play iso's through it. I believe it does trans-coding for media extenders like the 360 with additional software. And its free XD

Just curious - what edition of windows MCE do you have?

Comment: I've already tried it but I couldn't find a tutorial how to use it? I've Windows Home Premium Edition.

Comment: Their documentation is pretty decent - have you tried their quick start guide? 

http://community.mediabrowser.tv/permalinks/1303/media-browser-quickstart-guide

What version of windows? They currently only support Windows 7 flavors. _As of version 2.5.2 (codename Apollo) only Windows 7 is supported.
Version 2.5.1 (Hydra SP1) will be the last version that can be installed on Windows Vista._

Comment: I've Windows 7 Home Premium. I check the link but I've tried to use the plugin but I'm new to MCE. I only use it for TV and occasionally some video.